# TypeError: SSLCommerzPayment is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, payment-gateway

I am trying to access SSLCommerz transaction api for payment gateway integration, but on api call I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: SSLCommerzPayment is not a constructor
      at D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\src\pages\app.js:58:24
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at next (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
      at Route.dispatch (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
      at Function.process_params (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
      at next (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
      at jsonParser (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\BlockChain\21.06.2022_PaymentGateway\secondPart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: You likely need to show the portion of app.js around line 58 where that line occurs. It sounds like you are trying to `new` an object but what you are doing is not valid code (i.e. SSLCommerzPayment is not a class with a constructor). Have you read your API for documentation and examples?

Comment: SSLCommerz is a payment gateway with opensource in node js. In source it is shown that it has the class SSLCommerzPayment. See please here- https://github.com/ranasl62/npm-sslcommerz/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Yes, and? You *still* don't show the code that has the error. Is your `import` correct? The compiler *obviously* thinks "SSLCommerzPayment is not a constructor", so if you expect the API to work, your code is the problem and you need to show enough of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing package for SSLCommerz. I used sslcommerz-lts package and then the constructor don't show the error.

```
npm i sslcommerz-lts

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const SSLCommerzPayment = require('sslcommerz-lts')
const store_id = '<your_store_id>'
const store_passwd = '<your_store_password>'
const is_live = false //true for live, false for sandbox

const port = 3030

//sslcommerz init
app.get('/create-session', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        total_amount: 100,
        currency: 'BDT',
        tran_id: 'REF123', // use unique tran_id for each api call
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3030/success',
        fail_url: 'http://localhost:3030/fail',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3030/cancel',            
        shipping_method: 'Courier',
        product_name: 'Computer.',
        product_category: 'Electronic',
        product_profile: 'general',
        cus_name: 'Customer Name',
        cus_email: 'customer@example.com',
        cus_add1: 'Dhaka',
        cus_add2: 'Dhaka',
        cus_city: 'Dhaka',
        cus_state: 'Dhaka',
        cus_postcode: '1000',
        cus_country: 'Bangladesh',
        cus_phone: '01711111111',
        cus_fax: '01711111111',
        ship_name: 'Customer Name',
        ship_add1: 'Dhaka',
        ship_add2: 'Dhaka',
        ship_city: 'Dhaka',
        ship_state: 'Dhaka',
        ship_postcode: 1000,
        ship_country: 'Bangladesh',
    };
    const sslcz = new SSLCommerzPayment(store_id, store_passwd, is_live)
    sslcz.init(data).then(apiResponse => {
        // Redirect the user to payment gateway
        let GatewayPageURL = apiResponse.GatewayPageURL
        res.redirect(GatewayPageURL)
        console.log('Redirecting to: ', GatewayPageURL)
    });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Then I run in command prompt 'node index.js'
I got the output.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
import {SSLPayment}
```

to

```
import * as SSLCommerzPayment from 'sslcommerz-lts';
```

and it will work

Comment: Some explanation as to "why" it would work would be helpful for the questioner and the community

Comment: @HassanNaqvi I could not find the "why", as their code base suggests it should have worked. Let me know if you could find out why.
The least explanation I could find out was it didn't work in ECMA module loader

Comment: That should be a good enough answer to the why. A reference to the documentation or the lines of code from their codease that lead you to this conclusion are perfect answers for it.